# Concat in creating a function returns NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql

When I run the function it returns a null value even though it executes/creates the function without errors. Some values don't include a state which is why the address needs to be concatenated.

```
create or alter function CustomerFullAddress
(@CustomerID CHAR)
returns VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FullAddress VARCHAR

    SELECT @FullAddress = Concat(c.Address, ' ', c.City, ', ',
      c.StateOrRegion, ' ', c.PostalCode)
    from Customers c
    where c.CustomerID=@CustomerID 

    RETURN @FullAddress
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always provide a length when defining a `VARCHAR`.

If you don't the size is `VARCHAR(1)`

You should always explicitly declare the length of datatypes.

[Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)